# Masonry jQuery: how to append new items in the right side?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Using Masonry jQuery how to append new items in the right side instead of bottom?

Comment: What do you mean by that? What code have you tried? Where is your online sandbox or fiddle?

Comment: I have not created any application. I have only seen the examples at below link.
http://smashinghub.com/25-powerful-examples-of-masonry-jquery-web-design.htm
The examples in this link have only vertically append items function. I just want to know if it is possible horizontally append items. If yes, than what is the way?

Answer (score 0):

If you had read [the Masonry manual](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/adding-items.html), you'd seen that you can either *prepend* or *append* items. If you had read [the Isotope manual](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/adding-items.html), you'd seen that you can also either *prepend* or *append* items.

EDIT Then, you could use [this version of Masonry horizontal](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/tests/right-to-left.html) which appends. You just have to change the orientation. It's in the manual also, under Tests.

Comment: I already have read the manual. But it adds items vertically, I want to add new items horizontally where horizontal scrollbar will help to navigate the items.